# Can we get opening and closing time of other apps in our app?

Tags: android

In android, Can we get other apps opening and closing time in our app?.
our app should run continuously in background to get other apps time.

Comment: Please search in google for such a broad question. Ask code/problem specific question in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Broadcast Receiver**

You cannot track the opening and closing time of other app.
 If you have created own other application then you can track the closing and opening time of Application A inside Application B. If you want to achieve this feature the you need to use receiver with own event.